# Loading Fixtures Django

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to load some fixtures within my Django tests, but they don't seem to load.

In my settings.py, I specify:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dhtmlScheduler\\fixtures\\'))
```

Now, within my test case:

```
def setUp(self):
    fixtures = ['users.json', 'employee.json']
```

I should also probably mention that I'm using the Nose test runner:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

and unittest:

```
class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):
```

I must be missing something obvious, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Use a raw string for your directory there: `r'dhtmlScheduler\fixtures\'`. Easier to read. :)

Comment: Note to Luke and others: "Note that these paths should use Unix-style forward slashes, even on Windows." [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#fixture-dirs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FIXTURE_DIRS is supposed to be a list or tuple, not a string. Remember that it's the comma that defines a tuple litteral, not the parens, IOW your settings should be

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dhtmlScheduler\\fixtures\\'), 
    )
```

As a side note, hardcoding the path separator kind of defeats the whole point of using os.path.join(), so this should really be:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dhtmlScheduler', 'fixtures'), 
    )
```

Edit : and finally, you have to declare your TestCase fixtures at the class level, not in the setUp() method...

Comment: Thanks for the tips with the separator, but I still can't load the tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'fixtures'),)
```

*Or*

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
     fixtures = [
        '/myapp/fixtures/users.json', 
        '/myapp/fixtures/employee.json'
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test case file, Simply make reference to your predefined fixtures in this manner as shown below 
[image]